# Adding elements to a list: error "Constructor undefined "

Tags: java, processing

I want to add to my `activList` elements that have 3 parameters (an iD and their x y position) using: `activList.add(new Fiducial(iD, x, y ));`

```
import TUIO.*;
TuioProcessing tuioClient;

// Grid variables
int cols = 10, rows = 10;
int rectangleWidth = 100;
int rectangleHeight = 60;

// these are some helper variables which are used
// to create scalable graphical feedback
int k, l, iD;
float cursor_size = 15;
float object_size = 60;
float table_size = 760;
float scale_factor = 1;
float x, y;

ArrayList<Fiducial> activList;


public class Fiducial {

  public int iD; 
  public float x;
  public float y;
}

void draw() {
  // Begin loop for columns
  for ( k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for ( l = 0; l < rows; l++) {
      fill(255);
      stroke(0);
      rect(k*rectangleWidth, l*rectangleHeight, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight);
    }
  }


  // This part detects the fiducial markers 
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 

  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0; i<tuioObjectList.size (); i++) {
    TuioObject tobj= tuioObjectList.get(i);
    stroke(0);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
    rotate(tobj.getAngle());
    rect(-80, -40, 80, 40);
    popMatrix();
    fill(255);
    x = round(10*tobj.getX ());
    y = round(10*tobj.getY ());
    iD = tobj.getSymbolID();
    activList.add(new Fiducial(iD, x, y ));
  }
}
```

When running this, I get the error "The constructor FiducialDetection.Fiducial(int,float,float) is undefined" at this line:

```
activList.add(new Fiducial(iD, x, y ));
```

I don't get it, I defined it using:

```
public class Fiducial {

  public int iD; 
  public float x;
  public float y;
}
```

Why do I still get this error ?

Comment: because you don't have a constructor :P.  PS: I can see you want a struct, but you code seems to be in java

Comment: Should I add it in the Fiducial class ?

Comment: @Longwei Processing is based on Java so that's why :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add constructor with argument.

```
public class Fiducial {

    public int iD;
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public Fiducial(int iD, float x, float y) {
        this.iD = iD;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```